# Counting number of first orders purchased by customers

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have been trying to crack this coding issue and while I keep getting close I can't seem to get it.

I have two tables

Table 1 - Products

Columns:

```
Vendor Id, Vendor Name, Product Id, Product Name, Brand
```

Table 2 - Orders

Columns:

```
Customer Id, OrderDateTime, Product Id, Vendor Id
```

I am trying to find how many "first purchases" there have been for each product by vendor

```
SELECT B.PRODUCTID, B.PRODUCTNAME, B.BRAND, B.VENDOR , COUNT(DISTINCT(B.CUSTOMERID)) AS 'FIRST PURCHASE COUNT' 
FROM
(SELECT A.CUSTOMERID, MIN(A.ORDERDATETIME) AS FIRSTPURCHASE, A.VENDORID, A.PRODUCTID, C.PRODUCTNAME, C.BRAND, C.VENDORNAME
FROM ORDERS A

JOIN PURCHASES C
ON C.VENDORID = A.VENDORID

GROUP BY A.CUSTOMERID, A.VENDORID, C.PRODUCTID) AS B

GROUP BY B.PRODUCTID, B.VENDORID
```

I would like to create results in the following columns:

```
Product Id, Product Name, Brand, Vendor Name, First Purchase Count
```

I would also like the `Vendor Name` output to be 'purchased from vendorxyz' not just 'vendorxyz' where 'vendorxyz' is the name of the vendor 
and where there is no vendor listed the output to be 'other vendor'

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following query *might* be what you are looking for (I could not test it since you did not provide sample data and expected output).

It uses a `NOT EXISTS` clause with a correlated subquery to search the order table for the first order of each customer, and then aggregates by product and vendor.

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductId, 
    p.ProductName, 
    p.Brand, 
    p.VendorName, 
    COUNT(o.ProductId) FirstPurchaseCount
FROM
    Products p
    INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON  o.ProductId  = p.ProductId
        AND o.VendorName = p.VendorName
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Orders o1 
            WHERE 
                o1.CustomerId = o.CustomerId 
                AND o1.OrderDateTime < o.OrderDateTime
        )
GROUP BY    
    p.ProductId, 
    p.ProductName, 
    p.Brand, 
    p.VendorName
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

my latest attempt got the same output as when using yours. would there be issue in doing it my way?

Comment: I  would also like the `Vendor Name` output to be 'purchased from vendorxyz' not just 'vendorxyz' where 'vendorxyz' is the name of the vendor and where there is no vendor listed the output to be 'other vendor'

Comment: @sqlnewbiex : for this, just replace « p.VendorName » with « CONCAT('purchased from vendor ', p.VendorName) ». PS : with this query, VendorName will never be NULL, as it is used in JOIN conditions.